# Where are all the ghosts for Haunted?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Haunted achievements wants you to

> Meet the following ghosts:
>
> - Lucious the Depraved
> - Dataminer
> - Drury Brown
> - John Gorham Coffin
> - Fecklar's Ghost
> - The Archivist
> - The Tomekeeper

Where are these ghosts located?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a pretty good guide over at d3db [here](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/haunted).  It includes a spawn point strategy for farming the Act I ghosts.  The diablowiki also has a concise listing [here](http://www.diablowiki.com/Haunted).

[Lucious the Depraved](http://www.diablowiki.com/Lucious_the_Depraved) - a unique Grave Robber - found in Cemetery of the Forsaken  - Act 1

[Dataminer](http://www.diablowiki.com/Dataminer) - a unique Ghastly Gravedigger - found in the Defiled Crypt - Act 1

[Drury Brown](http://www.diablowiki.com/Drury_Brown) - a unique Ghostly Murderer - found in the Defiled Crypt  - Act 1

[John Gorham Coffin](http://www.diablowiki.com/John_Gorham_Coffin) - a unique Grave Robber - found in the Defiled Crypt - Act 1

[Fecklar's Ghost](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/fecklars-ghost)  or see also [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?824714-Complete-List-of-unique-Elite-monsters-in-Diablo-3) - Unique Enraged Phantom- Festering woods - Act 1

[The Archivist](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/the-archivist) - Unique Grim Wraith - The Unknown Depths - Act II

[The Tomekeeper](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/the-tomekeeper) - Unique Grim Wraith- Realm of Shadow - Act II

Comment: Any updates to this?

Comment: Updated, I might polish more later, but at least I fixed up the locations...

Answer (score 3):

The Tomekeeper can be found at the Realm of Shadow in Zoltun Kulle's Archives.
The Dataminer can be found only in the FAKE Defiled Crypt with the Jar of Souls.
John Gorham Coffin can be found only in the REAL Defined Crypt lvl 1(just where the door to the Chancelor's Tomb leads).

Answer (score 2):

[Lucious the Depraved](http://www.diablowiki.com/Lucious_the_Depraved) - [Cemetery of the forsaken](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Cemetery_of_the_Forsaken)

[Dataminer](http://www.diablowiki.com/Dataminer) - [Defiled Crypt](http://www.diablowiki.com/Defiled_Crypt)

[Drury Brown](http://www.diablowiki.com/Drury_Brown) - [Defiled Crypt](http://www.diablowiki.com/Defiled_Crypt)

[John Gorham Coffin](http://www.diablowiki.com/John_Gorham_Coffin) - [Defiled Crypt](http://www.diablowiki.com/Defiled_Crypt)

[Fecklar's Ghost](http://www.diablowiki.com/Fecklar's_Ghost) - [Festering woods](http://www.diablowiki.net/Festering_Woods)

The Archist - [The Unknown Depths](http://www.diablowiki.com/The_Unknown_Depths)

The Tomekeeper - [Realm of shadow](http://d3db.com/zone/i/realm-of-shadow)

**Note:** These are **random** and **rare** spawns so it wont be easy to find them,also keep in mind to check dead ends.

Answer (score 2):

I just found The Archivist in The Unknown Depths and he is indeed a Grim Wraith.

Answer (score 1):

Found The Archivist in the Unknown Depths.  Took about 15 runs through, but I found him in a dead end that was no where near the exit.  Good luck.